# Error: Failed to load the template in ES5 Angular2

Tags: angular

I am creating an angular2 app(AddressManager) using **alpha.25** version. following is the code  on which i am getting error :

**Component:**

```
var AddressManager;

(function(AddressManager, Service, Utils){
    'use strict';
    var AddManagerInfo = Utils.at({
        Component: {
            selector:'address-manager',
            appInjector:[Service.ManageAddress]
        },
        View: {
            templateUrl:'address-manager.html',
            directives: [angular.NgFor]
        },
        forClass: AddManager,
        parameters: [Service.ManageAddress]
    })

    function AddManager (ManageAddress) {
        this.appName = 'Address Manager';
        this.personInfo = ManageAddress.get();
    }

    AddressManager.AddManager = AddManager;
})(AddressManager || (AddressManager = {}), Service || (Service = {}), Utils || (Utils = {}));
```

**View:(address-manager.html)**

```
<div>Testing</div>
```

when i use `template:'<div>Testing</div>'` instead of  `templateUrl:'address-manager.html'`, it works fine. but incase of `templateUrl:'address-manager.html'` it is throwing error:

***Failed to load the template "AddManager"***

[image]

Comment: I had to actually use the whole path. i.e. your component is in app/addressmanager.js and the template as well you d use  templateUrl: 'app/address-manager.html',

Answer (score 2):

Angular 2 expects to have the absolute path to the templates.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-relative-paths.html

In order to use relative paths try adding a moduleId property to your component:

```
@Component({
     moduleId: module.id,
     selector: 'my-comp',
     directives: [],
     templateUrl: 'my-comp.html',
     styleUrls:['my-comp.css']
})
```